# Spring Security SessionRegistry java config only

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

Can someone provide real working code snippet on **how to get not empty SessionRegistry object in Spring Security using java config only** (without any XML).

I'm using **Spring Security v4.0.1.RELEASE**

And what I'm tried to do:

1. **Implemented hashCode() and equals() methods in UserDetails** with Apache Commons Lang:

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, "password", "id", "role", "description", "registrationDate", "enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj, "password", "id", "role", "description", "registrationDate", "enabled");
    }
```

2. **Enabled HttpSessionEventPublisher**:

```
    public class AppSecurityInitializer extends
            AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

        @Override
        protected boolean enableHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

3. **Defined beans** in security config class:

```
    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry getSessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy getSessionAuthStrategy(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy controlAuthenticationStrategy =
                new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry);

        return controlAuthenticationStrategy;
    }
```

4. **Set http security**:

```
    httpSecurity
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy).maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .and().and()
            .csrf().disable();
    return httpSecurity;
```

Code works, it's prevents me to login under the same user twise, but when I'm getting SessionRegistry in controller class, it's always empty.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if spring creates a different SessionRegistryImpl on its own.

What about

```
httpSecurity
    .sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .sessionRegistry(getSessionRegistry());
```

leaving out the sessionAuthenticationStrategy stuff?!

Comment: Can I avoid maximumSession ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow I don't think so but apparently if you set maximumSessions to -1 you allow unlimited sessions, just like default.